# how to use the developer tools IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

how do I use the developer tools in IE 8. 
I'm opening the site and click on Tools - > Developer Tools

a window will just pop up "Developer Tools" that's it. 
I thought it will display the source code of the particular website.

Does this work like "Firebug" in Mozilla?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for your question:**

IE Developer tools does not work as the firebug - closest is Opera Dragonfly

It has a similar functionality as the basic Firefox developer tools with no addon - Firebug. I feel that the Operas's (Dragonfly) one is a little bit better as it highlights the components live. You can also select the parts of the page and see their code. Where the IE's one does not support that as far I am concerned. Still as I had a look now the IE's is better than Mozilla's.

It allows you to make changes to the scripts, CSS and HTML and save it.

**If you want to use developer tools live I would use:**

1. Opera Dragonfly (or Mozilla with Firebug installed)
2. IE Developer Tools
3. Mozilla's Developer Tools (no-addon)